# Format number with two slashes

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to format the number with this code and it worked:

```
Range("E5:E" & v_col).NumberFormat = "###-#-##"
```

But I need to change "-" with slash "/" to have a number like it:

226/1/16

but it does not work and the error 1004 is occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an VBA-issue, it's a problem with the special meaning of a `/` in number formatting (it is used to format a fraction). Try to set the same format directly in Excel: It will throw an error *"Microsoft Excel cannot use the number format you typed"*.

If you want to have such a special character as part of your formatting, you have to *escape* it - signal to Excel that the following character is not meant to have a special meaning but you want to have it simply as character. Escaping is done using the `\`, so if you want to have a slash in your formatting, you write `\/`. In your case, the number format would be `"###\/#\/##"`